# SignalR service crashing on start up

Tags: c#, windows, service, signalr

I've just picked up a Signal R service from a predecessor. After installing, it will start and stop successfully. It might even do that a few times before failing to start with an error

```
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Object[])
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(System.Object, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Reflection.Binder, System.Object[], System.Globalization.CultureInfo)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.ServerFactory.ServerFactoryAdapter.Create(Owin.IAppBuilder)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.StartServer(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.HostingEngine.Start(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Engine.StartContext)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.DirectHostingStarter.Start(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Starter.HostingStarter.Start(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions)`
```

I've put error handling everywhere, but this error is not caught within the application, just the event log.

I found the following code in the service startup:

```
        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(this._signalRURL))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);

        }
```

The service starts a thread and then sleeps forever! I don't know why he would have done this, but I'm assuming there was a very good reason. I've removed the thread.sleep line and the service now runs and does not throw an error.

So, my questions are:

- why is the thread sent to sleep forever?
- why is he using a "using" statement?

I don't want to take out the code until I know why it was there in the first place.

Comment: If it works sometimes, I suspect that a timeout needs to be extended.  From the exception it looks like a signature is failing.  I suspect that the service needs some sort of proxy certificate and is sometimes failing because the response is taking too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*`why is the thread sent to sleep forever?`*

He is trying to  create a long running thread or message loop on the current thread in order to avoid the `exit of the main thread`.  It's a kind of `Application.Run` see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run(v=vs.110).aspx)  for more information.

Because when  you exit the `using statement` the WebApp will be disposed and `SignalR` will be no  more available

*`why is he using a "using" statement?`*

There is no  reasons to use the using statement because the SignalR was intended to  run until the end of application instance life

**update**

what I can suggest is to declare the var of type IDiposable like the folllowing

```
//your windows service
public class RunningInstance : ServiceBase
    { 
       //this will  be outscope of method start and WebbApp will  not disposed 
       static IDisposable signalRApp;
       //and in your onstart   

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

             signalRApp=WebApp.Start<Startup>(this._signalRURL);
        }

    }
```

**Note**

*`when  you assign your IDisposable to a static field it will be loaded when your type is loaded (ServiceBase in  this case), so your object will be disposed when  your containing type is unloaded`*

Comment: Thanks, Kamel - that makes sense. So, I'm wondering if when I stop the service and re-start it, the thread has not been aborted properly causing the crash on subsequent service starts. He's calling Abort on the thread when the service stops, so not sure why it would crash

Comment: @NickWright try  my  update and see  if SignalR was disposed correctly